# Running a simulator build using apple script

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, applescript

I want to write an AppleScript to launch my project on simulator at some scheduled time. I am using the following apple script but it do not run the project on my simulator. It quits the simulator, launch the XCODE but do not run the project on simulator though the target is correctly set to simulator. What should I do?

```
application "iPhone Simulator" quit
tell application "Xcode"
    open "Users:abhinav:myProject:Code:client:src:test.xcodeproj"
    tell project "test"
        clean
        build
        run
    end tell
end tell
application "iPhone Simulator" activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AppleScript support in Xcode is very broken and there is no support for a run verb. However, if you're using AppleScript you can get it to run by using system events in code like below:

```
tell application "Xcode"
    tell project "test"
        activate
    end tell
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Xcode"
        click menu item "Run Without Building" of menu 1 of menu item "Perform Action" of menu "Product" of menu bar item "Product" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```